# Mixed effects model with random and nested effects in lmer

Tags: r, nested, lme4, mixed-models

I want to run a linear mixed effects model with nested and random effects using lmer in R, but continue getting errors. Two questions: what is causing the errors and how can I fix my model to run the appropriate analyses? Thanks so much!

**Experimental design:** Four sites- each site has 2 plant species and 3 accessions for each plant species (6 accessions total). An accession is essentially a plant population and they are unique to a particular plant species. At each site, there are two treatments: plants given nitrogen enriched fertilizer and plants given nitrogen free fertilizer. All species and all accessions are present at every site. I collected data on plant growth and root traits and log-transformed variables as needed. I also set Accession (coded 1 - 6), Site (coded 1 - 4), and SoilN treatment (coded 1 and 2) as factors. All response variables are continuous.

**Data structure:**

`Species Accession       ID Site SoilN LeafNo  LogLeaf Height NodNo   SBMg

1    MESA         4 250975.1    1     1     15 1.178977   18.1     3 0.0876 
2    MESA         4 250975.4    1     1     12 1.082785   18.6     3 0.0896 
3    MESA         4 250975.4    1     1     20 1.303196   22.4    20 0.1395 
4    MESA         4 250975.5    1     1      8 0.908485   18.4     2 0.0727 
5    MESA         4 250975.2    1     2     57 1.756636   33.5    23 0.5665 
6    MESA         4 250975.2    1     2     60 1.778874   44.8    61 0.5394`

**Model:** I want to test the effects of treatment (SoilN), Species, and Accession on plant growth and root traits. I have been running two models- one for species and one for accession. I would like to test an interaction between species or accession and soil N, include site as a random effect, and nest accession within species. I wrote the following models:

```
 lf  <- lmer(LogLeaf ~ SoilN * Species   + (1|Species/Accession) + (1|Site), data=a)
 lf2 <- lmer(LogLeaf ~ SoilN * Accession + (1|Species/Accession) + (1|Site), data=a)
```

**Output:**

```
lf <- lmer(LogLeaf ~ SoilN * Species + (1|Species/Accession) + (1|Site), 
data = a)
Warning message:
   In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
   Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
   - Rescale variables?`

summary(lf)
    Linear mixed model fit by REML 
    t-tests use  Satterthwaite approximations to degrees of freedom 
    ['lmerMod']
    Formula: LogLeaf ~ SoilN * Species + (1 | Species/Accession) + (1 | 
    Site)
    Data: a

REML criterion at convergence: 109.5

 Scaled residuals: 
     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
  -4.9162 -0.2557  0.1309  0.5600  1.5150 

 Random effects:
    Groups            Name        Variance Std.Dev.
    Accession:Species (Intercept) 0.004266 0.06531 
    Site              (Intercept) 0.046332 0.21525 
    Species           (Intercept) 0.038957 0.19738 
    Residual                      0.109152 0.33038 
    Number of obs: 140, groups:  Accession:Species, 6; Site, 4; Species, 2

 Fixed effects:
                    Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          0.90231    0.23405   0.00000   3.855   1.0000    
SoilN2               0.73319    0.07247 129.76000  10.117   <2e-16 ***
SpeciesTRPR         -0.45583    0.29753   0.00000  -1.532   1.0000    
SoilN2:SpeciesTRPR  -0.26846    0.11621 132.12000  -2.310   0.0224 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) SoilN2 SpTRPR
SoilN2      -0.166              
SpeciesTRPR -0.619  0.128       
SlN2:SpTRPR  0.102 -0.620 -0.223
convergence code: 0
Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
    - Rescale variables?

anova(lf)
    Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Satterthwaite 
    approximation for degrees of freedom
                 Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F.value  Pr(>F)    
  SoilN         11.5037 11.5037     1 132.11 105.392 < 2e-16 ***
  Species        0.4513  0.4513     1   0.00   4.135 0.99998    
  SoilN:Species  0.5825  0.5825     1 132.12   5.337 0.02243 *  
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
- Rescale variables?`
```

For the accession model (lf2), I get the following warnings:

`lf2 <- lmer(LogLeaf ~ SoilN * Accession + (1|Species/Accession) + 
     (1|Site), data = a)
     Warning messages:
     1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
     unable to evaluate scaled gradient
     2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
     Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues`

`summary(lf2)
    Error in calculation of the Satterthwaite's approximation. The output of 
    lme4 package is returned
    summary from lme4 is returned
    some computational error has occurred in lmerTest`

`anova(lf2)
Error in calculation of the Satterthwaite's approximation. 
The output of lme4 package is returned
anova from lme4 is returned
some computational error has occurred in lmerTest
Analysis of Variance Table
                Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value
SoilN            1 13.4357 13.4357 121.8414
Accession        5  0.3728  0.0746   0.6761
SoilN:Accession  5  0.8892  0.1778   1.6127
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues`

**Other notes:**

1. The model runs if I nest Accession within Species within Site, although I'm not sure that's a correct way to analyze the data.
2. It also runs if I don't nest Accession within Species, but still include Site and Accession as random effects.
3. I do have some zeros in my data set because some of the plant died. I added data to determine whether the zeros were causing the issue, but continued to get errors.

Comment: Make sure when asking for help to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). There is no variable named `LogLeaf` in your example data. Do you really only have 6 observations and you are trying to estimate all these parameters? That seems a bit statistically inappropriate. Maybe you should be asking for statistic help over at [stats.se] rather than programming help here.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll fix it.

Comment: I asked for help at Cross Validated, but was unable to fix the issues, so I figured I'd try here as well. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: can you give the link to CrossValidated?

Comment: Sorry one more thing- I'm not trying to estimate parameters for 6 observations (I have several hundred observations). The 6 refers to specific plant populations that are unique to 2 plant species, so I want to nest the accessions within species to account for that.

Comment: Cross validated link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281867/mixed-effects-model-with-random-and-nested-effects-in-lmer